# Mondodb C# save dictionary with array value

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a mongo collection: `Fieldset` . `Fieldset` has List if embedded object `Field`.

`Field` has a `Dictionary<string, object> Config`, **I want to be free about the value of this dictionary**.

```
public class Fieldset
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Slug { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("Fields")]
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    [BsonElement("Config")]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Config { get; set; }
}
```

***this is an example of value i want to put in. some sort of key value collection***:

[image]

***When I save, this is the value I have in the mongo***.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. It worked like supposed to work>

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new MongoClient();
    var database = client.GetDatabase("SO3");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<Fieldset>("jobject");
    var id = new BsonObjectId(ObjectId.GenerateNewId()).ToString();
    var field =
        new Field
        {
            Config = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"value", "item1key"}, {"lable", "item1value"}}
        };
    var field2 =
        new Field
        {
            Config = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"value", "item2key"}, {"lable", "item2value"}}
        };
    var fieldset = new Fieldset
    {
        Id = id,
        Slug = "aa",
        Fields = new List<Field>
        {
            field,
            field2
        }
    };
    collection.InsertOne(fieldset);
}


{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c55b972ceb9443d385de936"), "Slug" : "aa", "Fields" : [ { "Config" : { "value" : "item1key", "lable" : "item1value" } }, { "Config" : { "value" : "item2key", "lable" : "item2value" } } ] }
```